# I am trying to run a task in my async method but it's giving me a ui thread error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
    public async void CreateListSectionAsync()
    {
        details.Children.Clear();
        details.Children.Add(new MessageGridTemplate()
        {
            Label = "Information",
            Text = "Fetching card details, please be patient"
        });
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // modify the UI
            details.Children.Clear();
        });

    }
```

But this gives a UI error.  Is the way I am calling the task not correct?

Comment: "a UI error" - what is the specific error it gives you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView`s or other views that highly modify the UI hate being on a separate thread. So when you call

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    // modify the UI
    details.Children.Clear();
});
```

the UI will exception because you are modifying the screen from a **non-UI** thread. Try calling the `details.Children.Clear` in a **Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread** call.

Even just adding or removing a single element won't be happy on a separate thread/context.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify UI elements from a background thread.

The appropriate mitigation is **not** `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`. A more correct approach depends on what kind of UI updates you're doing:

- To display the results of a background thread operation, use `await`.
- To display progress or multiple results of a background thread operation, use `Progress<T>` / `IProgress<T>`.
- To display updates as events are pushed to your app, use `SynchronizationContext` or `IObservable<T>.ObserveOn`.